# What causes eclipse to hang while disconnecting from workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I just installed eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04 (apt-get install eclipse-platform). Immediately afterwards I start eclipse (which works fine) and immediately close it. Then it hangs while saving workspace. The progress dialog says "Disconnecting from workspace".

Are there logs or something I can check to see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the eclipse log is `$workspace/.metadata/.log` where `$workspace` is your workspace root dir

Comment: The only files in there are .lock, .plugins/, and version.ini. I tried launching with -consoleLog and -debug. It produces some output during startup but nothing when I exit. And there still are no log files in that directory.